# How should I read the statement: $(\forall x)(Sx \to (\forall y)(Sy \to x=y))$?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

"There is at most one student" is symbolized as
$(\forall x)(Sx \to (\forall y)(Sy \to x=y)$

Earlier I asked this question [$(\forall x)[Mx -> (\forall y)(My -> Kxy)]$, can $x\;\&\; y$ be the same thing?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3517211/forall-xmx-forall-ymy-kxy-can-x-y-be-the-same-thing)

and they told me that x and y can be the same thing. Now in confused because I would read the statement above as "for everything, if it's a student, then, for everything else if it's a student, then they have to be the same student" which it would make sense. But if x and y can be the same I don't understand how I should interpret it. Could you guys help please?

Comment: For all $x$, if $x$ is a student, then every student is equal to $x$.

Comment: I don’t see your problem. Since “$x=y$” is a conclusion, it seems to me that *of course* $x$ may be $y$.

Comment: My problem is that i dont understand how I should read it, nobody speaks like this and it's so confusing. It should be read "for everything if it's a student, then for everything if it's a student, then they are the same" the "everything" confuses me, once you say it you're talking about everything already so why say it again... Its weird that I don't even know how to explain it clearly

Comment: Consider $x$ and $y$ ways to identify people. "If any person selected by process-x is a student, then: if any person selected by process-y is a student, then they must have selected the same person".  That is of course, just along winded way of saying "There is at most one student to select."

Comment: As per your [previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3515910/how-can-i-learn-to-read-predicate-logic-sentences) start from the simpler part: $(∀y)(Sy→x=y)$ means that "every student is equal to $x$". Then quantifiy over $x$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly your question is, but let me say

> "for everything, if it's a student, then, for everything else if it's a student, then they have to be the same student"

is not a good interpretation (not specifying the variables after quantifiers, and 'for everything else' means $\forall y $ such that $\lnot x=y$, which is not provided.).

> "for any $x$ if it's a student, then, for any $y$ if it's a student, then $x$ is $y$"

will be more precise. And also as Mauro said, not every logical formula can be translated into natural language. For example, *'is'* used in the statement just above, is used for equal ($=$). However, in natural language 'is' can mean several things such as *Josh is student*- here 'is' is used for relation, namely $\in$. (see $Sj\leftrightarrow j\in S$.)

Answer (score 0):

*Not every FOL formula has a "natural" natural language counterpart*...

But we can apply some useful transformations. First of all, we may convert the formula in the equivalent [prenex form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prenex_normal_form#Implication):

> $(∀x)(∀y)(Sx → (Sy → x=y))$,

followed by the tautological equivalence called [Exportation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exportation_(logic)) to get:

> $(∀x)(∀y)((Sx \land Sy)→x=y)$.

Now the reading is much more easy:

> "Every two students are identical".

Comment: Why do we even use all this it's so much easier in normal language

Comment: Natural language can also be rather *ambiguous* at times.  Formal symbolism is precise about what it means to say.

Answer (score 0):

Should $(\forall x)(Sx\to(\forall y)(Sy\to x=y))$ be true, then the statement $Sa\to(Sb\to a=b)$ will be true for any term $a$ and any term $b$ in the domain — whether these terms have the same value or not.

Now, when those terms have the same value, the statement holds whether a term of that value satisfies $S$ or not.    However, the statement *cannot* be satisfied by *two distinct* terms that satisfy $S$.

Thus the claim of $(\forall x)(Sx\to(\forall y)(Sy\to x=y))$ is that predicate $S$ can be satisfied by *at most one* entity in the domain.